# Responsive web pattern on the server side

Tags: java, scala, jakarta-ee, lift, responsive-design

I have been reading about the [responsive web pattern](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/) and I have successfully implemented it on a test page. However I see the limitations of that the layout is limited by the order/sequence of the HTML tags. You can set the `display:none` property on a lot of content etc but that is not nice.

So is there a way on the server side to distinguish between what the HTML response are going to include based on what kind of device is used by the user? I am mainly interested in Scala (Lift) and Java EE solutions.

Comment: There won't be "the" solution. I haven't heard of a framework that allows you to render content depending on device without too much code duplication. Maybe you are more looking for a powerful template language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Lift you can identify the userAgent and if it is mobile, you can show different html than if the user is using a desktop browser.

There are a few ways to accomplish this, one is from the Sitemap, or another is from each snippet.

The [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/liftweb) is a good place to ask the specifics of each method.

**Update**

This is an example using Sitemap from Lift

```
def sitemap = SiteMap(
  Menu.i("Home") / "index" >> pickTemplate(),
  Menu.i("First") / "first" 
)

//Show mobile or regular page
def pickTemplate() ={
  //If the browser is Chrome, pick this template
  if(S.request.map(_.isChrome) openOr true  ){
    Template( ()=>Templates("chrome" :: Nil) openOr (NodeSeq.Empty))
  } else{
    Template( ()=>Templates("other" :: Nil) openOr (NodeSeq.Empty))
  }
}
```